# Can I keep all the contents in my jar file in just one sentence when I run proguard?

Tags: java, android, proguard

When I use proguard in android studio, I notice that there are `-keep class mypakageName.**{*;}` to keep the class in my package and `-keep interface mypackageName.**{*;}` to keep the interface in my package etc... but I find it is fussy, can't I keep all the files in my package in just one sentence? Or is there a method can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `-keep class` will keep any java type, including classes, interfaces, enums.

Comment: I use dex2jar and jd-gui to see the code which has been obfuscated(and I use -keep class to keep all the code for test), then I see the interface and the normal class files were not obfuscated, but all the enum shows "//INTERNAL ERROR//", why?

Comment: It seems that it's ok, because when I use -keep enum * {*;}, I still get the "//INTERNAL ERROR//".